# SQL join with multiple Postgres tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, join

I have a PHP script that reads a user input which in turn returns a JSON array of data based on the value they enter.

The idea is to join two Postgres tables together, and then select all entries where the user value equals that of the uprn column (where this column is an integer).

I have a similar PHP script which works ok so PHP etc is set up correctly, but when trying this code it returns a 500 - Internal Server Error.

Have I correctly assigned the single quotes in the right positions for both my query entry, and my array rows?

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['query'])) {
    // Connect to our database
    $conn = pg_connect("host=myhost port=myport dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass");

    // Retrieve the query
    $query = $_GET['query'];

    // Search the database for all similar items
    $sql = pg_query($conn, "SELECT l.uprn, l.ward, r.ward, r.name FROM addresses.temp_addresses_plus_wards AS l LEFT JOIN council.councillors AS r ON l.ward = r.ward WHERE l.uprn = {$query}");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = pg_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $address = array(
        'ward' => $row['r.ward'],
        'name' => $row['r.name']
        );
        array_push($array, $address);
    }

    sort($array);

    $jsonstring = json_encode($array);

    // Return the json array
    echo $jsonstring;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I just needed to remove the table alias for my array and it now works!